# How to yank the text on a line and paste it inline in Vim?

Tags: vim

Say, I have the following lines:

```
thing();
getStuff();
```

I want to take `getStuff()` using the `yy` command, go forward to `thing()`, placing the cursor on `(`, and paste via the `p` command, but since I yanked the whole line, `p` will paste `getStuff()` right back where it was.

I know you can first move the cursor to the beginning of that `getStuff()` line and cut the characters from there until its end via the `^D` commands—then <kbd>p</kbd> will do what I want. However, I find typing `^D` to be much more tedious than `yy`.

Is there a way to `yy`, but paste the line *inline* instead?

Comment: someone mentioned, `yy`, then in insert mode: `<C-r>*`, but it would be awesome if this stripped out tabs and newlines..

Comment: In insert mode, put the cursor exactly where you want, use `Ctrl + r`, then `"`. Now, `Esc`  `k` `Shift + j`. The last combination will strip out tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> ("yank inner word") instead of <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to yank just what you want:

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> is line-wise yank and will grab the whole line including the carriage return, which you can see if you look at the unnamed register (`""`) in `:registers` which is used as the source for pastes.  See `:help ""`:

> Vim uses the contents of the unnamed register for any put command (`p` or `P`)
> which does not specify a register. Additionally you can access it with the
> name `"`. This means you have to type two double quotes. Writing to the ""
> register writes to register `"0`.

An additional benefit to <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> is that you don't have to be at the front of the "word" you are yanking!

Comment: ah this is sweet because even if your cursor is in the middle of a word, it will yank the whole word inline. Thanks

Comment: You may find `y i W` useful in some cases.

Comment: Where do I find documentation on commands like `yiw` or `yiW`? Simply typing `:h yiw` or `:h inner` or going to `:h yank` and searching for "inner" does not work. Stack becomes the de facto manual for me, but that doesn't help when I'm offline.

Comment: @ClintChelak See `:help text-objects` There are quite a lot of them, and they apply to more than just `y` which is the action.

Answer (score 53):

The problem is that <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> is copying the entire line, including the newline. An alternative would be to copy from the beginning to the end of the line, and then paste.

<kbd>^</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>

- <kbd>^</kbd> Go to the first character of the line.
- <kbd>y</kbd> Yank till
- <kbd>$</kbd> End of line.

// Credit to: tester and Idan Arye for the Vim golf improvements.

Comment: while this is pretty nice and solves my newline problem, say I have a bunch of tabs before `getStuff()`.. I end up copying `\t\t\t\tgetStuff()`.. which I end up having to go back and edit out anyways.. I wish there was a way to strip out tabs and newlines with a paste command..

Comment: ah it looks like you can go `^y$` this is pretty short, but I would still like to find a tab removing function so I don't have to `^`

Comment: You can use `_y$`. What `_` does is `[count] - 1 lines downward, on the first non-blank character |linewise|.`. Without the `[count]`, it's the same as `^`, but `_` is much easier to reach on the keyboard.

Comment: ^ and _ go to the first non-blank character on the line, so they won't pick up the tabs.  If you want the leading whitespace, use 0 instead, as in 0y$

Comment: I have `nnoremap Y y$` in my vimrc, so that `Y` yanks to the end of the current line (similarly to `C` and `D`). This would save a keystroke in the above solutions.

Answer (score 11):

One way to simplify the routine of operating on the same text patterns
is to define mappings that mimic text-object selection commands.

The two pairs of mappings below—one for Visual mode and another for
Operator-pending mode—provide a way to select everything on the current
line except for the new line character (`al`), and everything from the
first non-blank character of the current line through the last non-blank
character, inclusively (`il`).

```
vnoremap <silent> al :<c-u>norm!0v$h<cr>
vnoremap <silent> il :<c-u>norm!^vg_<cr>
onoremap <silent> al :norm val<cr>
onoremap <silent> il :norm vil<cr>
```

Thus, instead of using `yy` to copy the contents of a line that
is to be pasted character-wise (and not line-wise), one can then
use the `yal` or `yil` commands to yank, followed by the `p` command
to paste, as usual.

Comment: I think you meant `omap` (recursive mappings), since they refer to `al` and `il` just created

Comment: @AndréWillikValenti: `:omap` would be required if those two mappings were *not* defined in terms of `:norm`. In other words, mappings `:onoremap <silent> al :norm val<cr>` and `:omap <silent> al val` have the same effect and differ only stylistically.

Answer (score 9):

A less efficient, but simple method:

- <kbd>v</kbd> to highlight the word(s),
- <kbd>y</kbd> to yank the highlighted word(s),
- <kbd>p</kbd> (at the end of the line) you want to paste